# ResponseInterceptor at OpenFeigh 11.7

Tags: spring, feign

I am trying to create a ResponseInterceptior ate Spring Boot 2.6.13 Open Feign. But the 11.7 version the ResponseInterceptior doesn't exist anymore.

Someone know how to use in this version or in Open Feign 12.2?

How to do this new ResponseInterceptor

```
class MyResponseInterceptor : ResponseInterceptor {
  override fun aroundDecode(invocationContext: InvocationContext?): Any {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As per open feign git repo, ResponseInterceptor interface is still available for use in its latest revision (12.2).

Link: https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/ResponseInterceptor.java

Can you share more info if this doesn't solve your issue, e.g. pom.xml dependancy details or yaml details.

Comment: I need a example of how to use.

Comment: `code` class MyResponseInterceptor : ResponseInterceptor {
      override fun aroundDecode(invocationContext: InvocationContext?): Any {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}

Comment: This looks like typescript? I thought question was tagged for java